# iPhone KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, report, segmentation-fault

Im not sure why I am recieving this error, and I'm unable to track down the cause. This only happens on the device though, Simulator runs error-free as expected. Can anyone make sense of this crash log?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x61f6490a
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x32668edc 0x32665000 + 16092
1   Foundation                     0x33f70990 0x33f29000 + 293264
2   Foundation                     0x33f82a66 0x33f29000 + 367206
3   Foundation                     0x33fdb2d8 0x33f29000 + 729816
4   CFNetwork                      0x31f5903a 0x31f05000 + 344122
5   CFNetwork                      0x31f0fa58 0x31f05000 + 43608
6   CFNetwork                      0x31f0f8e8 0x31f05000 + 43240
7   CFNetwork                      0x31f0f892 0x31f05000 + 43154
8   CFNetwork                      0x31f0f812 0x31f05000 + 43026
9   CFNetwork                      0x31f0f7b2 0x31f05000 + 42930
10  CoreFoundation                 0x32da43a0 0x32d4d000 + 357280
11  CoreFoundation                 0x32da3c18 0x32d4d000 + 355352
12  GraphicsServices               0x31bb936c 0x31bb5000 + 17260
13  UIKit                          0x30bf3c28 0x30bf0000 + 15400
14  UIKit                          0x30bf2228 0x30bf0000 + 8744
15  MobileProfiles                 0x000020b6 0x1000 + 4278
16  MobileProfiles                 0x0000202c 0x1000 + 4140

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327be720 0x3272d000 + 595744
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327604d8 0x3272d000 + 210136
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3275fc9c 0x3272d000 + 208028
3   Foundation                     0x33f91acc 0x33f29000 + 428748
4   Cyntact.dylib                  0x000b72b6 0xb6000 + 4790
5   Foundation                     0x33f7cac6 0x33f29000 + 342726
6   Foundation                     0x33f2ad0e 0x33f29000 + 7438
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3272e4b8 0x3272d000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x32731094 0x3272d000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                 0x32da4002 0x32d4d000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                 0x32da3c18 0x32d4d000 + 355352
4   WebCore                        0x32f486f0 0x32ec4000 + 542448
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 3:
0   CFNetwork                      0x31f36364 0x31f05000 + 201572
1   CFNetwork                      0x31f23084 0x31f05000 + 123012
2   CFNetwork                      0x31f093d6 0x31f05000 + 17366
3   CFNetwork                      0x31f5b066 0x31f05000 + 352358
4   CFNetwork                      0x31f0a16e 0x31f05000 + 20846
5   CFNetwork                      0x31f506bc 0x31f05000 + 308924
6   CFNetwork                      0x31f511a4 0x31f05000 + 311716
7   CFNetwork                      0x31f517a6 0x31f05000 + 313254
8   CFNetwork                      0x31f51842 0x31f05000 + 313410
9   CFNetwork                      0x31f51950 0x31f05000 + 313680
10  CoreFoundation                 0x32dd8d9c 0x32d4d000 + 572828
11  CoreFoundation                 0x32dd8f10 0x32d4d000 + 573200
12  CoreFoundation                 0x32da43a0 0x32d4d000 + 357280
13  CoreFoundation                 0x32da3c18 0x32d4d000 + 355352
14  Foundation                     0x33f83998 0x33f29000 + 371096
15  Foundation                     0x33f7cac6 0x33f29000 + 342726
16  Foundation                     0x33f2ad0e 0x33f29000 + 7438
17  libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327532f0 0x3272d000 + 156400
1   CoreFoundation                 0x32d6d7e2 0x32d4d000 + 133090
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x001efaa0    r1: 0x3196dff8      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x01010019
r4: 0x61f6490a    r5: 0x00042707      r6: 0x31062706      r7: 0x2ffff50c
r8: 0x0016b3d0    r9: 0x001fc098     r10: 0x000000d0     r11: 0x00109580
ip: 0x385c23d0    sp: 0x2ffff40c      lr: 0x33f70997      pc: 0x32668edc
cpsr: 0x000f0010
```

Comment: Symbolicated crash log please. Compile your code with -g, then enter "backtrace" in GDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's something to get you started.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: So the answer is, enable NSZombieEnabled and you will know?

Answer (score 1):

mn ur XCODE (4.3) next the play button :) (run)

select : edit scheme

the scheme management window will open

click on the Arguments tab

you should see : 1- Arguments passed on launch 2- environment variables

inside the the (2- environment variables) place Name: NSZombieEnabled
Value: YES

And its done....

Answer (score 0):

Symbolize the log,  aka drag it into organizer,  and the log will make sense.